# How to do ylim plot Limits with Holoviews Bokeh Datashader

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews, datashader

How do I add y-limits (ylim) to a plot created using Holoviews Datashader?

I have tried the hv.Dimension function and also adding ylim=() parameters but it would either be the Holoview that rejects it or the Datashader function that doesn't understand the parameter.

```
plot_Z1 = datashade(hv.Curve(df).redim(y=hv.Dimension('y', range=(-50,50))))
plot_Z2 = datashade(hv.Curve(df).redim(y=hv.Dimension('y', range=(-50,50))))

plot_Z1.options(width=500) + plot_Z2.options(width=500)
```

ylim isn't recognized and hv.Dimension has no effect

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce any issue with the code you have provided, the dimension range works for me and at least since 1.11.0 ylim is recognized as an option.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that I cannot use ylim and shared_axes together with Holoview datashading. At least not in the sense where shared_axes works properly that it will zoom in/out on all subplots together. If I stick to just Holoviews either it won't apply the ylim or the shared_axes won't zoom in/out on all subplots (only one plot with zoom while others stay still).

The only way I found to get shared_axes working properly together with a ylim parameter is using HVPLOT instead.

```
plot_1 = df.hvplot(y='Something', width=200, datashade=True)
plot_2 = df.hvplot(y='Something Else', width=200, ylim=(-50, 50), datashade=True)
plot = (plot_1 + plot_2.options(shared_axes=True)).cols(1)
plot
```